# Como ejecutar una consulta de otra base de datos con variables declaradas

Tags: sql

bueno tengo un pequeño problema, les comento:
 Quiero enviar algunos datos de una tabla a otra igual pero de otra base de datos:
lo que pasa es que el nombre de la base de datos la tengo en una variable, ya que no sera estática porque esa variable puede aceptar otras bases de datos(ojala me deje entender) en si no puedo concatenar esa variable a la consulta.

El código es este:

```
Create proc Detalle_Traslado(@Cod_Stock  int ,@Cantidad int,@Sucursal_Salida varchar(100),@Sucursal_Destino varchar(100),@msje varchar(70) output)
as 
begin
declare @Fecha varchar(10)
declare @NombreBD varchar(100)
declare @Nombre_Producto_Salida varchar(100)
declare @nombre_Produto_Llegada varchar(100)
set @Fecha=getdate()
set @NombreBD=(select DB_NAME(@Sucursal_Destino))
set @Nombre_Producto_Salida=(select p.Descripcion from Stock s inner join Producto p on p.Cod_Producto=s.Cod_Producto where s.Cod_Stock=@Cod_Stock)
set @nombre_Produto_Llegada=(select * from @NombreBD.dbo.)

end
go
```

Donde:

Las sucursales son los nombres de base de datos. lo que quiero es primero comprar que si existe un nombre de producto igual en las dos bases para poder enviarlo si no existe no se podrá hacer el envió de mercadería.